# ASP Net 7 Razor checkbox value was empty even it was checked

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have this checkbox inside a form of a Bootstrap 5 modal. It was generated using Html.CheckBoxFor as shown below:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m.RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
   <label class="form-check-label ps-2" asp-for="RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER">@commonLocalizer.Get("ResetFailedLogin")</label>
</div>

[BindProperty]
public bool RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER { get; set; }
```

When the form was submitted via Ajax, its value was empty and its related hidden field value was "false". This has caused a model validation error in the back-end code.

As indicated in the form values, RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER value = "" and RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER hidden field = "false".

[Form values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSygp.jpg)

Rightfully, it should be "true" and "false" respectively.

To make it works, before form submission, I need to set the checkbox value using jQuery as shown:

```
$('#RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER').val($('#RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER').is(":checked"));
```

I am not sure if the issue was caused by loading of record data via Ajax in a BS modal form. I didn't encounter this issue in other main pages.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: "When the form was submitted via Ajax, its value was empty " Could you share you ajax code about submit   `RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER` ?

Comment: There is no issue with Ajax submission. Referring to the attached form values screen, RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER value was empty and its hidden field value was "false". RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER value should be "true".

Answer (score 0):

> $('#RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER').val($('#RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER').is(":checked"));

Change to:

```
$('#RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER').is(":checked");
var RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER = $('#RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER').val();
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I didn't try your code as there is no issue with my script below: 

$('#RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER').val($('#RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER').is(":checked"));

Actually, I want to know why RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER value = "" and RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER hidden field = "false". Instead, they should be "true" and "false" respectively.

Comment: @Ryan Ong  Your  $('#RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER').val($('#RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER').is(":checked")); don't set value for RESET_LOGIN_COUNTER successfully. So it will be value = "".